# I want to get the information of a torrent file in a desired format through python

Tags: python, torrent, bencoding

I am writing code to parse tracker information in torrent file using python.

```
import bencoder
import sys

target = './'+sys.argv[1]

with open(target, 'rb') as torrent_file:
    torrent = bencoder.decode(torrent_file.read())

i=0
while True:
    try:
        print(torrent[b'announce-list'][i])
        i+=1
    except:
        break
```

The output is as follows.

[b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce']

[b'udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce']

I want to parse the value in the form below.

["tracker.openbittorrent.com", 80]

["tracker.opentrackr.org", 1337]

How should I parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) for this as follows

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url1 = b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce'
url2 = b'udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce'
c1 = urlparse(url1)
c2 = urlparse(url2)
hostport1 = c1.netloc.rsplit(b':',1)
hostport2 = c2.netloc.rsplit(b':',2)
hostport1[0] = hostport1[0].decode()
hostport1[1] = int(hostport1[1])
hostport2[0] = hostport2[0].decode()
hostport2[1] = int(hostport2[1])
print(hostport1)
print(hostport2)
```

output

```
['tracker.openbittorrent.com', 80]
['tracker.opentrackr.org', 1337]
```

Explanation: I extract netloc, then split at most once at first from right `b':'`, then apply `.decode` to host port to convert `bytes` into `str` and `int` to convert `bytes` into `int`.

EDIT: After more careful reading, I noticed that you might access `.hostname` and `.port` which allow much more concise code to do that task, that is

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url1 = b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce'
url2 = b'udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce'
c1 = urlparse(url1)
c2 = urlparse(url2)
hostport1 = [c1.hostname.decode(), c1.port]
hostport2 = [c2.hostname.decode(), c2.port]
print(hostport1)
print(hostport2)
```

gives same output as code above.

Comment: how can i convert [b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce'] into url1 = b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce' ??

the way i thought
in str([b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce'])
How to remove [ and ]. Is this the best way?

Comment: @Sliced_ice `[b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce']` is just list with single element, you need to get first element that is `url1 = [b'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce'][0]`